Transaction spamming on dedicated node
So I wanted to know if I have my own node and want to land a transaction in all this mess. Would it benefit me spamming my node let's say same tx every second until blockhash expires or after a certain amount of attempts is there no benefit to keep sending even if the blockhash hasn't expired?

If you're sending the transaction to your node via RPC, then your node's RPC server will retry the transaction automatically until it expires.
If you're sending to your node's TPU port, then it will not retry for you, so you'll have to keep resending.
